# How do I output whole files from a map job?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

This is a basic question about mapreduce outputs.

I'm trying to create a map function that takes in an xml file and makes a pdf using apache fop. However I'm a little confused as how to output it, since I know that it goes out as a (key,value) pair.

I'm also not using streaming to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? Some jumping off point for how to help you with your code would be good.

Answer (score 0):

The point of map-reduce is to tackle large amount of data that would usually not fit in memory - so input and output would usually be stored on disks somehow (a.k.a. files). 
Input-output must be specified in [key-value format](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html)

```
(input) <k1, v1> -> map -> <k2, v2> -> combine -> <k2, v2> -> reduce -> <k3, v3> (output)
```

I have not tried this but this is what i would do:

Write output of mapper to this form: `key` is the filename in [Text](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html) (keep filename unique) and `value` is the output of fop in [TextOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/TextOutputFormat.html). Write it using [TextOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/TextOutputFormat.html).

**Suggestion:**

I am assuming that your use case is just reading input xml (maybe doing some operation on its data) and writing data to PDF files using [fop](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/). I dont think this is a hadoop use case in first place...becoz whatever you want to do can be done by a batch script. How big are your xml files ? How many xml files do you have to process ?

**EDIT:**

[SequenceFileOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/SequenceFileOutputFormat.html) will write in a [SequenceFile](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile). [SequenceFile](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile) has its own headers and other metadata along with the text that is stored. Also it stores data in form of key:values.

```
SequenceFile Common Header

    version - A byte array: 3 bytes of magic header 'SEQ', followed by 1 byte of actual version no. (e.g. SEQ4 or SEQ6)
    keyClassName - String
    valueClassName - String
    compression - A boolean which specifies if compression is turned on for keys/values in this file.
    blockCompression - A boolean which specifies if block compression is turned on for keys/values in this file.    
    compressor class - The classname of the CompressionCodec which is used to compress/decompress keys and/or values in this SequenceFile (if compression is enabled).    
    metadata - SequenceFile.Metadata for this file (key/value pairs)
    sync - A sync marker to denote end of the header.
```

Using [SequenceFile](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile) ruin your application as you will end up with corrupted output PDF files. Try [this](http://srijiths.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/sequence-files-in-hadoop/) out and see for yourself.

You have lots of input files...and this is where hadoop sucks. [(read this)](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/). Still I feel that you can do your desired operation using a script to invoke [fop](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) on every document one by one. If you have multiple nodes, run the same script but on different subset of input documents. Trust me, this will run FASTER than hadoop considering the overhead involved in creating maps and reduces (you dont need reduces..i know).

Comment: Well, the reason that we're trying to use hadoop is because we're going to need to generate roughly 1,000,000 pdfs at one time frequently. Now I did look at a tutorial I found at [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html) that explains a bit more about inputs and outputs. So for the output, I'm thinking maybe I could use the SequenceFileOutputFormat, but I'm really not sure how that would output exactly since theres no reducer. I also ran into another example where they put a null value for the return value, and just returned the key but I don't remember where that was

Comment: @user1325360 see my EDIT above